# Is it possible to have the intersection of two strings without using a loop in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, performance

I would like to ask you if it was possible to get the characters common to two strings without having to resort to a loop on the character array. I wonder why this could greatly affect the total cost (asymptotically for n-> infinite) of algorithms such as eg. Charm or Eclat (just think that it would be like adding a new cycle to those already present). Thank you.

[image]

Specifically, the algorithm I am referring to is the following. As can be seen from the photo (line 6) it is necessary to obtain the intersection by iterating on the indices i and j, so I suppose it is necessary to iterate. I guess I get an O(m + n) best assuming the insert and search operations use O(1).

Comment: How would you imagine being able to find out what characters are in a string without iterating over it?

Comment: corollary - if you *do* know what characters the string has, you do not need to iterate over it... but...

Comment: you can "transform" a loop into a recursive call... into a "loop in disguise"

Comment: The answer is a qualified yes.  You would need to maintain strings as a compound data structure that combines both the sequence of characters and an efficient set structure containing the unique characters of the string. Then the intersection of characters in two strings a and b can be calculated in O(min(N(a), N(b)). Where N(s) is the number of unique characters in s. In other words,  you can save the cost of traversing the more complex string.

Comment: @user2864740 That's why I said qualified.  The OP asked for a way to avoid scanning both strings. This is one. It has no asymptotic cost.

Answer (score 1):

If your characters are byte-encoded (US-ASCII, KOI8-R, etc), you can create array, where your char is index, and iterate 1st string, and set "1" here. Thereafter, iterate 2nd string, and print only chars, presents in the array. See the example:

```
void print_intersection(const unsigned char *s1, const unsigned char *s2) {
    unsigned char arr[0x100], c;
    bzero(arr, sizeof(arr)); // cleanup
    while(c = *s1++)
        arr[c] = 1;
    while(c = *s2++)
        if(arr[c] != 0) {
            putchar(c);
            arr[c] = 0; // Disable print dups
        }
}
```